# Nose - Is it possible to stub a class constant?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, nose, stub

N00b at Nose framework here.

Looking at the docs for unittest.mock, I do not see an obvious way to stub a variable. I am testing a class with constants declared. One constant is a really large int and for testing purposes, I'd like to replace it with a much smaller int.

My understanding is that you can only mock (with the @patch decorator) a function, and not a variable.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the patch decorator to replace a constant.  e.g.:

```
>>> import mock
>>> class Foo(object):
...   bar = 1000000
... 
>>> with mock.patch.object(Foo, 'bar', 10):
...   print(Foo.bar)
... 
10
>>> print(Foo.bar)
1000000
```

Specifically, look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) for the `new` keyword argument to `patch` (or any of the various items in the `patch` family)...

<sup>I'm on python2.x where `mock` was still a 3rd party module.  Changing to `from unittest import mock` should make the above code work for you.</sup>